# Linux: Checking if a user has a shell or not

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a test script in python where I use subprocess to run various terminal commands and check the result. One of the things I want to check is if the user "games" doesn't have a shell. I don't want to log in as games(which I think is impossible anyway), but have the ability to run this command as root. Is there any single bash command I can use to check what shells another user has(or doesn't have)?

I'm able to use the command "cat /etc/shells/" to check what shells I have available, I wanted to use this to search another user but I'm not sure how to do it, if it's even possible.

Comment: What if shell is set to `/bin/false`?

Comment: `getent passwd games | cut -d: -f7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use "su", and check the return code:

```
root@shinwey:# su games
This account is currently not available.

root@pifa:/home/kalou/t# echo $?
1
```

or print the string "NO_SHELL":

```
root@shinwey:# su games 2>&1 > /dev/null || echo NO_SHELL
NO_SHELL
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. I used the first two commands in my python script and it seems to give me the result I want